# C# .DLL Library - Best Practices for Console and Form Windows apps

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, console

Over the years I've written my own Windows `.dll` in C# which includes many objects and functions that I normally use.  Up until now, all my programs have been console applications so my dll functions write their status, errors and output to the console.  For example: `"Loading polygon file : Fred.txt"` or `"Imported 268 polygons from file"`. Now I'm starting to write Windows Forms programs and I want to reuse the dll functions, but obviously I can't write to the console for a Forms app.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to the best way to handle a dll which contains functions to be used for both console and forms programs?  Is it best to have two versions of every function?  Are there ways to tell if a function is called from a Form and not write to the console?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: For example, you can have one dll which is writing to some stream(you can use StreamWriter for that). You will pass the stream to the Dll main object constructor and your dll will work with that stream. As a stream you can pass Console.OpenStandardOutput() or any FileStream, or something else

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to display the messages in your windows forms application?  Typically DLLs don't deal with UI operations, such as displaying messages.  They *can* however deal with logging, if that's what you're actually looking for.  I would say you should look into a logging framework like NLog and implement that in your DLL.

If you have a WinForms project that references the DLL, you could pass information up from the DLL and display at the UI level.  It's a question of proper application architecture.  Ideally, the DLL would know nothing of the way it's being used, i.e. from a console application vs. a WinForms app.

Answer (score 0):

"but obviously I can't write to the console for a Forms app."

That's not at all true. You *could* allocate a console, and write the information to it. So you'd have your forms, and also a console that's writing your output. That works great for debugging.

Or, you could redirect the console output to a file. Just pass a reference to an open `StreamWriter` to `Console.SetOut`, and everything that you were writing to the console goes to that file. It's a great way to do some informal logging.

If you're wanting to display the methods' outputs and error messages in the Windows Forms app, then you have to give them somewhere to send the output. That will probably require a lot of rewriting your library methods. The idea is that, rather than writing to the console, those methods would call an output method that you supply. *That* method would probably be part of an interface. Still, that's not a particularly good way to do things because it assumes that your library knows how you'll want information reported in every user interface scenario.

In general, you probably don't want worker methods to supply user interface output. Logging, sure, but you probably don't want the function that loads data from the file to output to the user: "Loaded 287 records from file." Instead, you have something like:

```
// in your console program
List<Thing> things = LoadThingsFromFile("filename.txt");
Console.WriteLine($"Loaded {things.Count} things from file.");

// in your Windows Forms application
List<Thing> things = LoadThingsFromFile("filename.txt");
StatusLine.Text += $"Loaded {things.Count} things from file.";
```

`StatusLine.Text`, of course, is just an example. You might have this in a scrolling list or pop up a message box, etc. The point being that you want the UI code rather than your processing code to decide how information should be communicated to the user.